# ffmpeg - how to create a "dynamic scaling" effect?

Tags: ffmpeg

I was trying to create a new video(1920*1080):

1. black background
2. overlay a central video getting bigger with time(from 960*540 -> 1920*1080 )
   from an input(the central,1920*1080).

But failed with "zoompan","scale","crop"
"Scale" seems benifit, but it can't run with timestamp args.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62846651/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help!